# How to get $auth value in component outside of registered vue-router component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have a layout theme/default which has vue-router inside like this

```
<template>
<div id="app">
    <component :is = "layout">
       <router-view></router-view>
    </component>
</div>
</template>
<script>
const default_layout = "theme";
export default {
computed: {
    layout(){
        return ( this.$route.meta.layout || default_layout) + '-layout';
    }
},
};
</script>
```

And then the theme layout is like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="app-home">
        <nav-bar/>

        <div class="container-fluid section">


                <div class="left-fixed">
                    <side-bar/>
                </div>
                <div class="right-card">
                    <slot />
                </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  import NavBar from './Navbar'
  import SideBar from './Sidebar'
  export default {      
       data() {
      return {

      }
    },
    mounted(){



    },
    components: {
      NavBar,
      SideBar
    }
  }
</script>
```

Now I have to pass current auth user in Navbar and Sidebar for logout and current user role which can be obtained from vue-auth $auth but only inside router component. Can anybody help it to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using vuex I had made a state which I call as computed property and I set whenever User logged in.